# Javascript/jQuery: Loop through array values inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
var myJSON =     
{"data":
    [{"obj1":"value1",
      "obj2":"value2"},

     {"obj1":"value3",
      "obj2":"value4"},

     {"obj1":"value5",
     "obj2":"value6"}]
};
```

I've got an array looking like one above. I'd like to loop through each `obj2` and get the values. How can this be done in Javascript/jQuery?

I tried using:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myJSON.data.length; i++) {
    console.log(i.obj2);
}
```

but it looks as though `myJSON.data` doesn't return a length...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access the obj2 key from your i variable, which isn't your array. Try this way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myJSON.data.length; i++) {
    console.log(myJSON.data[i].obj2);
}
```

Other ways to do the same:

```
for(var i in d=myJSON.data){
  console.log(d[i].obj2);
}
```

or

```
myJSON.data.forEach(function(a){
  console.log(a.obj2)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

`i` is only an iterator you can use to access the array

```
for (var i = 0; i < myJSON.data.length; i++) {
    console.log(myJSON.data[i].obj2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < myJSON.data.length; i++) {
    console.log(myJSON.data[i].obj2);
}
```